# issue with using svgr/webpack in next.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack, next.js

Trying to add [SVGR](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack) into the next.js project.

The issue with a building project, getting error:

```
 Module not found: Can't resolve '@svgr/webpack'
```

Setps:

1. Installed svgr as devDependecies
2. Add svgr into next.config.js

```
webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.svg$/i,
    issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
    use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
});
```

3. Import svg file as Component
4. Build the project and error happens

Has anyone had a similar problem?

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Could you provide a codesandbox example (or similar)?

Comment: Solve it, problem is cus I installed svgr in devDepencies, and I am using in also in run time not just build time. 

Just moved package from devDepen to depencides